# Proving that a specific Volterra integral operator is not positive

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I want to prove that the operator
$$ A: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1], \quad A(u)(s) = \int_0^1 |t-s| u(t) dt $$
is not positive, i.e. $\langle Au, u \rangle \geq 0$ does not hold for every $u \in L^2[0,1]$.

I could not find a counterexample but I think it is possible to prove that this operator has a negative eigenvalue which would imply my claim.

Any idea how to construct a counterexample for the claim itself or maybe an eigenfunction corresponding to a negative eigenvalue?

Comment: It seems that $u(s) = 1-2s$ is a counterexample

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you very much!